Why doesn't mnemonicPrefix work when diff'ing a stash?
If I run
git -c diff.mnemonicprefix=true diff stash@{0} $(git branch --show-current)

the first line in the output is still
diff --git a/file.txt b/file.txt

as if I hadn't used diff.mnemonicPrefix.
Why is this? And can it be "fixed"?

you are comparing two commits (stash@{0} and the head of your active branch), I think mnemonicprefix keeps the standard a/... b/... in this case.

A stash is not one of the cases listed in https://git-scm.com/docs/diff-config#Documentation/diff-config.txt-diffmnemonicPrefix where this option would change the output.

But isn't a stash ultimately implemented as a commit? See here e.g. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18527171/how-does-stashing-work-in-git-internals
